# How can you group by the result of a case if case is not supported in the group by clause in intebase

Tags: sql, interbase

I have tried using the columns alias, column number, using the case statement in the group by with no luck. Is this a shortcoming of interbase?

`select
  case
    when vp.preferredvendor = 'Y' then vp.name
    else 'Misc'
  end as vendor,
  sum(sa.totalfare)
from
  SalesActivity(1,1,2, '2014-01-01', '2014-02-01') sa
join
  booking bk on bk.bookingno = sa.bookingno
join
  profile vp on bk.vendor_linkno = vp.profileno
group by
  vendor`

Comment: It would be helpful to show us the all of the queries that you tried (you mention three, but only show one), along with the actual error message you receive for each of them.

Answer (score 1):

Repeat the `case`:

```
select (case when vp.preferredvendor = 'Y' then vp.name
             else 'Misc'
        end) as vendor,
       sum(sa.totalfare)
from SalesActivity(1,1,2, '2014-01-01', '2014-02-01') sa join
     booking bk
     on bk.bookingno = sa.bookingno join
     profile vp
     on bk.vendor_linkno = vp.profileno
group by (case when vp.preferredvendor = 'Y' then vp.name
               else 'Misc'
          end);
```

As a side note, some databases do allow the use of column aliases in the `group by` clause, but definitely not all of them and it is definitely not required by the standard.

Comment: It returns an sql error saying there is an invalid token right after the group by.  Sory  interbase does not support the case in the group by portion of the statement.

Comment: @wizhippo . . . Are you allowed to do `group by vendor` or use subqueries?

Comment: dosen't support `group by vendor` or subqueries.  Best I can do is use a view and then group by using the view.  Seems like a bad limitation of interbase.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with Interbase, but given what you've tried unsuccessfully, the next step would be to try a sub-query:

```
select vendor, sum(totalfare)
from (
   select
     case
       when vp.preferredvendor = 'Y' then vp.name
       else 'Misc'
     end as vendor,
     sa.totalfare
   from
     SalesActivity(1,1,2, '2014-01-01', '2014-02-01') sa
   join
     booking bk on bk.bookingno = sa.bookingno
   join
     profile vp on bk.vendor_linkno = vp.profileno)
group by vendor
```